# R iterating through 50k dataframe took long

Tags: r, csv, parsing, dataframe

I'm writing a simple program which should parse one .tsv file into multiple .csv files. Problem is that it took so terribly long (I think 9 minutes on ~50k rows is horrible performance). Please can somebody look on my code and tell me what am I doing wrong?

I have a table which contains `name of participant`, `name of media`, `timestamp`, and some coordinate data. In my data there can be one or more participants and every participant worked with 2 media files. And I want to create csv file for each of `media files` concrete participant worked with.

For example I have 2 participants `P1` and `P2` and each worked on media files `M1` and `M2`. So I want to create `P1_M1.csv`, `P1_M2.csv`, `P2_M1.csv`, `P2_M2.csv`.

Data looks like this:

```
P1 | M1 | data...
P1 | M1 | data...
...
P1 | M2 | data...
...
P2 | m1 | data...
...
...
```

Here is my code:

```
data = read.table("./data.tsv", header = T, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F) # load data from tsv

# function for creating csv file
writeData = function(filename, d){
  filename = paste("./", filename, ".csv", sep = "")
  write.csv(d, file = filename, row.names = F)
}

# initialize auxiliary variables
participantName = ""
mediaName = ""
# initialize empty dataframe
subdata <- data.frame(TimeStamp = numeric(), GazeLeftX = integer(), GazeLeftY = integer(), GazeRightX = integer(), GazeRightY = integer())

# for each row in original data...
for(r in 1:nrow(data))
{
  # check if last participant is same as participant on actual row
  if(participantName != data[r, 'ParticipantName']){
    # check if last participant is not empty (like no participant was processed yet)
    if(participantName != ""){
      # if it is not than participant and also his work on media file ended so write data to csv
      writeData(filename = paste(participantName,"_",mediaName, sep = ""), d = subdata)
      # empty auxiliary dataframe and also mediaName
      subdata = subdata[0,]
      mediaName = ""
    }
    # we detected new participant so record it into last participant variable
    participantName = data[r, 'ParticipantName']
  }
  # do same checks for media file because there can also change only mediafile and participant can be the same
  if(mediaName != data[r, 'MediaName']){
    if(mediaName != ""){
      writeData(filename = paste(participantName,"_",mediaName, sep = ""), d = subdata)
      subdata = subdata[0,]
    }
    mediaName = data[r, 'MediaName']  
  }
  # in every iteration append actual row into auxilliary dataframe
  subdata = rbind(subdata,
                  TimeStamp = data.frame(data[r, 'EyeTrackerTimestamp'],
                  GazeLeftX = data[r, 'GazeLeftX'],
                  GazeLeftY = data[r, 'GazeLeftY'],
                  GazeRightX = data[r, 'GazeRightX'],
                  GazeRightY = data[r, 'GazeRightY']))
}
# if there are any data left in auxiliary dataframe, save it to csv
if(nrow(subdata) != 0){
  writeData(filename = paste(participantName,"_",mediaName, sep = ""), d = subdata)
}
```

Comment: See `?split`. Try for instance `split(data,data[,c("ParticipantName","MediaName")])`.

Comment: @nicola thank you so much. this is perfect. please you can post an answer if you want and I will mark it as solution. Now I have only one problem that my code create just one csv file but there is probably just some stupid mistake in my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `?split`. Try for instance:

```
split(data,data[,c("ParticipantName","MediaName")],drop=TRUE)
```

that will create a `list` containing a `data.frame` for each `ParticipantName`-`MediaName` pair. If you want to write each dataframe on a different file, you can try something like:

```
res<-split(data,data[,c("ParticipantName","MediaName")],drop=TRUE)
Map(writeData,names(res),res)
```

where `writeData` is the function you defined.